# Build a plugin as a form input element with firebreath

Tags: npapi, firebreath, browser-plugin

we can develop a plugin as a form element with qtbrowserplugin.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtbrowserplugin/developingplugins.html#using-plugins-in-forms

Can we do the same thing with firebreath? Are there any example available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I have never heard of this before.  FireBreath does not have any such feature at present, but if you can figure out what qtbrowserplugin is actually doing behind the scenes it should be fairly trivial to add support to firebreath for the same thing.

Comment: I build a plugin with firebreath and try to use it as a form element. I am surprised that it works in IE, but not google chrome or firefox. In IE, the value of the element is returned from ToString(). Can someone give me a hint how to make it works for chrome and firefox as well?

Comment: this is totally a shot in the dark, but try the "value" property

Comment: I add a "value" property to my plugin. IE grabs the "value" property instead of ToString() now. However, chrome and firefox are still not working.